# transpose data in excel and make automatic tables

Tags: excel

I have data like this:

[image]

want to make it like this:

[image]

but this should be done automatically because the original data have more than 2000 rows. and I need the final tables to be decorated in the way I want. (they have border are centered , there are space between them and ...)
any suggestions?

Comment: This is fairly easy, first have you tried anything? What is your level of experience with VBA?

Comment: @HolmesIV , I dont know VBA at all just search what ever i need every time, in this case I tried to make final table in word . linking word and excel file. but i didn't get the result i want. decorating and making final tables look the way i need is so important here

Comment: Would you want the new tables on a new sheet? Or just under the table?

Comment: please share what you had tried... at least. search online for : using index match or vlookup .  as @HolmesIV stated, without a sample file/data/screenshot, we cannot know where is your input range, and where is you output cell range.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, I am not sure where you want it written out.

```
Sub Create_List()

Dim Info() As Variant
Dim I, II, Ct As Long

Info = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Value

''Go where you want the list
ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Activate

Ct = 0

For I = 2 To UBound(Info, 1)
    For II = 1 To UBound(Info, 2)
      ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 0).Value = Info(1, II)
      ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 1).Value = Info(I, II)
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 0).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 0).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 0).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

     With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 1).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Offset(Ct + II - 1, 1).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    Next
    Ct = Ct + UBound(Info, 2) + 1
Next

End Sub
```